# PHP - preg_match or equivalent on multiple HTML Lines Object to create array

Tags: php, regex, fpdf

I'm using a piece a code which looks like this (from fpdf to create an array with the html tag attribute as key then the value)

```
//Extract attributes
$a2=explode(' ',$e);
$tag=strtoupper(array_shift($a2));
$attr=array();
$attrStyle=array();
foreach($a2 as $v)


    if(preg_match('/([^=]*)=["\']?([^"\']*)/',$v,$a3))
    $attr[strtoupper($a3[1])]=$a3[2];



    $this->OpenTag($tag,$attr);
```

It works just fine when $v is something like that.

- `src="images/intro_doc_AA.png"`
- `alt="intro"`
- `width="388"`
- `height="408"`

but with HTML5 style format (can't change that) sometimes I have for $v something like that:

- `style="width:`
- `300;`
- `height:`
- `485;"`

And I'm trying to get something like that so I can use it:

```
$attrStyle=Array(width->300, height->485)
```

Thanks for your time, NG.

Comment: You may want to use a DOM parser rather than a RegEx.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (preg_match('/([^=]*)=(["\']?)(.*?)\2/s', $v, $a3)) {
    $attr[strtoupper($a3[1])]=$a3[3];
}
```

But it's obvious: bettter to do not parse HTML by RegExp.